# Is it possible to read an emmc on an android device sector by sector?

Tags: android

I'm just curious if it's possible to read the **raw emmc** on an android device sector by sector. I have been searching for fastboot source files for a while but i'm not sure if it does the reading part itself. Can anyone show me a path to start from?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to open the raw device file, in /dev

Comment: no permission, i'm on unrooted device.

Comment: Well, then there's your answer.

Comment: adb is not the only way to read emmc, there's also download mode which you can reach sectors.

Answer (score 0):

On an un-rooted device, no.

You need to open the raw device file in `/dev`.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a way to read the emmc in download mode. Adb is too high-level for trying this in my opinion. There must be an executable that can read raw emmc